# bootstrap-wysiwyg Set Content

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-wysiwyg

How to set content to bootstrap-wysiwyg editor dynamically with jQuery.
I tried

```
$('.editor').html() and $('.editor').val()
```

Seems to like none of them are accepting

Answer (score 2):

After struggling  lot I found the way

```
var editorObj = $("#description").data('wysihtml5');
var editor = editorObj.editor;
editor.setValue(data.description);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this, `$("#editor").html("I am a <b>bold</b> text.");`

wysiwyg editor will show as content as expected as below

"I am a **bold** text"

Comment: I tried this But it is not working. However I found the way and have post as an answer.  --Thanx mate

Comment: Your solution did not work for me though it is smart way. How ever the answer I post is working as I anticipated. --Ta

Comment: I tested with simple `.html(content)` jQuery function. It works well.